# Derivation of $G=\frac{\hbar c}{m_\rm{P}^2}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants, absolute-units

I read that the gravitational constant can be expressed in terms of Planck length.

$$G=\frac{\hbar c}{m_\rm{P}^2}$$

What is the derivation of this relationship?

Comment: Hey spraff, have you looked at the Wikipedia article for [Planck mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_mass)? It seems like there's a lot of information there that should be relevant to your question.

Comment: $m_P$ is the Planck mass, not the Planck length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s simply because the [Planck mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_mass) is *defined* as

$$m_\text{P}=\sqrt{\frac{\hbar c}{G}}\approx 21.8\text{ micrograms}.$$

This particular combination of the reduced Planck constant, the speed of light, and Newton’s gravitational constant — and no other — happens to have the dimensions of mass.

We don’t know yet whether it is the mass of anything in particular, such an undiscovered elementary particle, the smallest possible black hole, etc. When we have an accepted theory of quantum gravity, the meaning of this mass will probably become clear.

It’s much larger than the mass of any known elementary particle, and much smaller than known astronomical masses. As Wikipedia amusingly points out, it’s about the mass of a flea egg... something on a rather mundane and easily comprehended scale.

Obviously there is nothing “quantum gravitational” about Planck-mass flea eggs. But to understand Planck-mass black holes *does* require a theory of quantum gravity, because not only is their mass scale the Planck mass, their length scale is, at least naïvely, the Planck length and their time scale (for Hawking evaporation) is the Planck time.